# Cannot Activate Sandbox Solution

Tags: 2010, event-receivers, sandbox-solution

I'm trying to activate a sandbox solution on a SharePoint site but the 'Activate' button is greyed out.  I have made sure that the Sandboxed Code Service is started but it's still not enabled.  What else may cause this sort of behaviour?

Comment: Does Sandbox WSP contains any .net code, if yes, do you access Solutions Gallery as a Site Collection Admin?

Comment: Yes it contains .net code to update list items.  I also have access to the solution gallery and a site collection admin and to the farm as a farm administrator.